# What is Capacitance for a Spherical Shell pair?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

Consider three Scenarios :

1) [image]

In this case , we are Calculating

$$\frac{d(Q_b)}{d( \triangle Vab)} $$

2) [image]

In this case , we are Calculating

$$\frac{d(Q_a)}{d( \triangle Vab)}$$

3) [image]

In this case , we are Calculating

$$\frac{d(Q_b)}{d( \triangle Vinfinityb)}$$

---

So , how do we actually define Capacitance for a Pair of Spherical Shells ?

Comment: Duplicate/related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189056/capacitance-of-spherical-capacitor-when-earthed