# Capacitance of spherical capacitor when inner surface of outer sphere is earthed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Let there be two concentric shells in which the outer sphere contains charge Q1 and inner sphere contains charge Q.Capacitance of spherical capacitor when the inner surface of the outer sphere is earthed is: $$C={4\pi \varepsilon_{0}b}.$$

But the charge present in the outer surface of the inner sphere(Q) has a potential (V).
Hence there is a Potential Difference between the outer surface of the inner sphere and the inner surface of the outer-sphere.
Potential difference :$$ V=\frac{Q}{4\pi \varepsilon_{0}a}$$
[image: Spherical Capacitor]

So the capacitance is $$C1=\frac{Q}{V} = {4\pi \varepsilon_{0}a} $$

And total capacitance: $$C={4\pi \varepsilon_{0}a}+{4\pi \varepsilon_{0}b} $$
where does the derivation is go wrong?

Comment: From where did you get that potential difference?

Comment: the potential of the inner sphere minus the potential of inner surface of outer-sphere = V-0 =V

Comment: The voltage on the outer sphere isn't what you wrote

Comment: earthed surface must have potential equal to zero ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this as a resource to work through it. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html

Grounding the inner surface of the outer shell of a concentric spherical capacitor sets the voltage at that surface to zero. Since we have the reference voltage defined as $V_{R\rightarrow\infty}=0$ this means there is no electric field outside of the system of concentric shells. What this implies is that if you place charge Q on the inner sphere, opposite and equal charge -Q will flow onto the inner surface of the outer sphere such that it negates the field outside of the system. It turns out that this is the same picture as the one we get in the link above, the only difference being there is no electric field once you pass outside of the inner surface of the outer shell. Thus the capacitance should come out the same:$$C= \frac{4 \pi \epsilon_0}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}}.$$
It's important to understand that the voltage or charge placed on the outer shell has no bearing on the capacitance, since by Gauss' Law the field is determined solely by the charge contained within the Gaussian surface in question.

Comment: if there is a charge initially in the outer sphere (Q1). so when -Q charge is induced in the inner surface . To balance it the outer surface of outer sphere gets charge Q1+Q.so that the net capacitance is  C= (4πϵ0ab/a-b)+(4πϵ0b) right? But in my book it is given that its only 4πϵ0b

Comment: And the second thing... If the inner surface has zero potential it means the +Q charge flows from earth to inner surface of outer sphere.which makes net charge zero in the inner surface. Then how will be the electric field outside the inner surface gets negated?

Comment: What is the book you are referencing? If I can look at the problem perhaps I can better understand how to solve it.

Comment: i dont have the book currently but this link may give the idea::https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/189070/260532