# Capacitance of spherical capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I was deriving the expressions for capacitance for spherical capacitors and i am completely confused now.please help!
Outer sphere is B with radius b and inner sphere is A with radius a.

CaseI- sphere B is earthed( +Q given to sphere A)

(i) *outer surface earthed:*
Potential on B is just due to -Q (induced charge) as potential of outer surface is 0(it is earthed) and V on A is due to +Q charge given to it.now **the two surfaces of B are at different potentials so why doesnt charge flow between them** and their potential difference become zero?

(ii) *inner surface earthed*
Induced charge on the inner surface due to inner sphere goes to earth. Then is the potential due to charge on A or is there somehow charge induced on outer surface of sphere B?

Case II sphere A earthed (+Q given to B)

(i) *outer surface earthed*
No charge induced on inner sphere... system behaves as isolated spherical conductor B.
C=4(pi)(epsilon)b.
Is my reasoning correct?

(ii)*inner surface earthed*
Why does the **Charge on outer sphere distribute on inner and outer surface** when a conductor’s charge always resides on its surface?

Please point out any inconsistencies or wrong assumptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capacitance of spherical capacitor when earthed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189056/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that capacitance is essentially a geometric property: it does not depend on the charge or how it was induced, so it is the same in all cases.

When we are dealing with two conductors, one of which is grounded, we are dealing with the phenomenon of screening: the charge on the grounded conductor builds up till it screens the electric field due to the charge on the other conductor. The charge doesn't flow between the two conductors because they are not connected (otherwise it wouldn't be a capacitor).